# FormControl is not provided by any applicable directives

Tags: html, angular, typescript

FormControl is having difficulties with directives...

I am trying to implement an autocomplete into my input field. I am using the following angular-material guide to the point that I have verbatim copy and pasted their typescript and html to test it out: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview.

I keep receiving an error on FormControl in the HTML that reads: "Property FormControl is not provided by any applicable directives nor by input element.  Inspection info: Reports undefined property, event or structural directive bindings on elements."

```
 HTML CODE:

 <form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [FormControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

 TS CODE:

 import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
 import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
 import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
 import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';

 @Component({
   selector: 'mySelector',
   templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
   styleUrls: ['myCSS.css'],
 })
 export class myExportClass implements OnInit {
   myControl = new FormControl();
   options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
   filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

   ngOnInit() {
     this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
       .pipe(
         startWith(''),
         map(value => this._filter(value))
       );
   }

   private _filter(value: string): string[] {
     const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

     return this.options.filter(option => 
 option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
   }
 }
```

Comment: Stupid questions: did you import the appropriate material modules such that the component has access? Also did you reexport the material modules?

Comment: And... have you imported ReactiveFormsModule?

Comment: `[FormControl]` should begin with lowercase: `[formControl]`

Comment: @MikeTung I believe so

Comment: @jpavel I tried both recommendations before posting, they do not work:/ the code above is exactly as it is on angular material website

Comment: In the website they also put a link to a stackblitz demo. It's a working code. Try to figure out what is different in your code compared to what is on stackblitz. BTW, I'm pretty sure it's `formControl` (lower case 'f'). If it's different in material site, it's likely a typo.

Comment: Verbatim copy and paste from stackblitz is not working, lower case is not the issue

Answer (score 8):

As stated in the docs: ["For this example, be sure to import ReactiveFormsModule from @angular/forms into your NgModule"](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#simple-autocomplete)

So ensure that your app.module contains the module e.g.:

```
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: importing `ReactiveFormsModule` only (without `FormsModule`) also worked for me, using Angular 7

Comment: FormsModule is for Template Driven Forms.
ReactiveFormsModule is for Reactive Forms.